# WebRTC on Android: TURN server is working properly but couldn't connect peers with different network

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android, rfc5766turnserver

I'm trying to implement WebRTC on Android for p2p communication. Then I tried to clone one of the examples from [here](https://proandroiddev.com/webrtc-sample-in-kotlin-e584681ed7fc). In that project, I noticed that he used a STUN server to create peer a connection between devices.

```
private val iceServer = listOf(
        PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer(),
    )
```

I tried to launch the app then it works fine until I change one of my devices' connectivity from local Wifi to 4G mobile data. This definitely means that 2 devices are behind different networks. So I changed my ICE server to a public TURN server from `openrelayproject`. I've tested the TURN server and it works properly based on trickle ICE.

[image]

However, the video call performed in the program still not working and the recipient screen keeps getting blank. I also tried to use TCP in the TURN server like [he](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64056854/11621203) does, but no difference.

**Is there something I could do to fix this?** I also don't know how to pass the data to the TURN server, or is it done automatically? Any code example would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

check replay raddr from server and client (android), need both same network